# "Microsoft Action Pack Development and Design" subscription will also give me MSDN subscription?

Tags: msdn

If I subscribe to "Microsoft Action Pack Development and Design" https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/Pages/Membership/subscribe-action-pack-dev-design.aspx

After subscribing do I also get a MSDN subscription?

> "Microsoft has increased the value of the Action Pack in a couple of
>   ways: 1) by breaking it into two editions, Solution Provider for VARs
>   and solution providers, and Development & Design for ISVs, developers,
>   and web designers at companies with fewer than 100 employees; 2) by
>   adding a TechNet subscription to the Solution Provider edition and an
>   MSDN subscription to the Development & Design edition."

Reference http://blogs.technet.com/b/msuspartner/archive/2011/02/23/microsoft-action-pack-subscription-offers-benefits-engagement.aspx

Comment: Why is this a c# question?

Comment: Yep, it's a good deal. For more information, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223581/action-pack-design-and-development-am-i-missing-something.